# How to reset referenced Workbook variables

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a workbook `A`(A.xlsm) which references the workbook `B`(B.xlsm) via the `Tools -> References` menu in the VBA editor. `A` uses several macros in `B`. If I close `A` then `B` remains open and all variables maintain their current state. Therefore if I open `A` again, some macros in `B` will give errors because they have the state from previous incantations which is not compatible with `A` anymore.

Is there a way to reset `B` so that all variables are now in the original state?
Alternatively is there a way to close `B` once `A` is closed?

Comment: You are right. There is normally no need to close / reset variables with VBA. This is because the scope of VBA variables is normally rather low. Variables (normally) live and die with the procedure or function within which they are used / created: https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/variable-scope-lifetime.htm But if you are creating variables with a wider scope then you should get ready to release / reset them with lines of code like `Set ws1 = Nothing` or `strVariable = vbNullString` or `lngRowCount = 0` or `Set adoRecordSet.Close` and then `Set adoRecordSet = Nothing`....

Comment: @Ralph In my case it is Module variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the variables, I would suggest you write a CleanUp-Sub in the referenced workbook `B` and call it from `A`.

To close workbook `B` when `A` is closed needs a kind of hack. You cannot simply issue something like `close Workbooks("B.xlsx")`, it will throw an error (*1004 - workbook is currenlty referenced by another workbook...*).

Look at a trick that David Demner suggest here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18132384/7599798. The idea is that in the referenced workbook, a closing routine is triggered but the `close` is not immediately executed. You call it when your workbook is closed, but the `Close` (of `B` will only be executed after the the close of the calling workbook  (`A`) is done.